# Regex to match Centos Prompt

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl script which uses the following regex to match the prompt on Ubuntu:

```
[>#%\$](?:\033\[0m \S*)?\s*$
```

However, on CentOS, my prompt is returning the following, which does not match with the above regex:

```
[root@my-device-name ~]#
```

How can I modify the above regex so that it matches with both Ubuntu and Centos prompts?

Comment: Can you give more examples of the prompt ? I suppose this is in the home directory, how is the output in other directories ?

Comment: This does match you prompt. (https://regex101.com/r/AWIW9S/2)

Comment: @totok This is how the prompt looks in home directory and other directories:    [root@my-device-name user1]# cd core/
[root@my-device-name core]#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've manage to write this one :

```
^(\[.+@.+\]#)\s(.*)$
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/mhtOAm/3/)

The first capturing group captures the begining of the line , and the second, the command.